# ion-refresher - spinner not showing

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem with the `ion-spinner`.

The pulling text and icon are showing up:
[image: Pulling text and icon]

But when I release it, the area where the spinner should be stays empty.

[image: Spinning icon]

My `ion-refresher` is like this

```
<ion-refresher
        pulling-text="Pull to refresh..."
        on-refresh="doRefresh()"
        spinner="crescent">
</ion-refresher>
```

The doRefresh() function

```
$scope.doRefresh = function() {
    Entry.all().$promise.then(function(data) {
        $scope.logs = data;
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    });
}
```

What´s going on?

#### UPDATE:

I tested every spinner and the only one working is `spiral` but way too big. Only about half of the spinner is visible

[image: Spiral Spinner]

According to the docs http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionRefresher/ the `ionSpinner` should work

Answer (score 14):

if someone else runs into this issue, for me this fixed it:

```
ion-refresher {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Why only 10? Those are rookie numbers! You gotta pump those numbers up! ;)

Comment: this causes the refresher to overlay content. Better then to do: ion-content {background-color: transparent;}

Comment: this fixes but come over my contents

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I experienced the same problem, and I found a solution.
The spinner has always been there, but it is white, so you can't see it with a white background. To fix this, add following code to your CSS-file, replacing "skyblue" with your choice of color.

```
.spinner svg {
  stroke: skyblue;
  fill: skyblue;
}
```

Also, here is my ion-refresher.

```
<ion-refresher on-refresh="collectFeed()" pulling-text="Pull to refresh" spinner="ios-small"></ion-refresher>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely too late, but this happened to me. Basically I had overwritten `.spnner svg {}` in the css file and forgot. So, all the later loading spinners kept taking the same height and width.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that `<ion-refresher>` is directly below `<ion-content>`.

Answer (score 0):

Behavior of all spinners is not persistent in ionic,You can use other spinners like `android`, `spiral` etc and see which works for you.

Comment: I tested every ionSpinner but it seems  that only the spiral is working. I added this to my question

Answer (score -1):

```
<span>
<ion-refresher
        pulling-text="Pull to refresh..."
        on-refresh="doRefresh()"
        spinner="crescent">
</ion-refresher>
<span>
```